# Android MonoGame application closing immediately after being resumed

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

Using MonoGame 3.7.1 I have a very basic game setup on Android. There is some weird behaviour with closing/reopening the app.

To exit the game, I use this logic:

```cs
if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
{
    Activity.MoveTaskToBack(true);
    //Exit(); //Originally was using this, neither seems to have changed much
}
```

However, when resuming the app it will occasionally (and seemingly at random) open and then immediately close (not crash). It doesn't always do this, sometimes it returns back to it's previous state without any issues. If I attempt to resume it again it will open as normal.

I have captured a video showing this behaviour [here](https://1drv.ms/v/s!AjogeBky-tuamqNvujz-dBWYglOgaw?e=cpFpji). It's worth noting that there's no crash happening. This is running in Debug via Visual Studio with the phone connected via USB so if it was a crash I'd know. This behaviour happens even when not in debug mode.

The debug output when the unexpected closing happens is this:

```
05-22 23:27:05.228 E/SensorManager(26381): registerListenerImpl sensorName:BMI160_ACCELEROMETER Accelerometer Non-wakeup,isWakeUpSensor:false,callingApp: TestGame.TestGame,callingPid:26381,callingUid:10569
05-22 23:27:05.245 D/DecorView(26381): onWindowFocusChangedFromViewRoot hasFocus: true, DecorView@8012b96[MainActivity]
05-22 23:27:05.265 W/monodroid-assembly(26381): typemap: unable to find mapping to a managed type from Java type 'com/google/android/gles_jni/EGLSurfaceImpl'
05-22 23:27:05.265 D/MonoGame(26381): GraphicsDeviceManager.ResetClientBounds: newClientBounds={X:0 Y:137 Width:1080 Height:1799}
05-22 23:27:05.265 D/AudioTrack(26381): ClientUid 10569 AudioTrack::start 
05-22 23:27:05.317 E/SensorManager(26381): unregisterListenerImpl callingApp: TestGame.TestGame,callingPid:26381,callingUid:10569
05-22 23:27:05.325 D/        (26381): PlayerBase::stop() from IPlayer
05-22 23:27:05.325 D/AudioTrack(26381): ClientUid 10569 AudioTrack::stop 
05-22 23:27:05.325 D/AudioTrack(26381): stop(1656): called with 1772 frames delivered
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #17
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #28
```

The only things that stand out to me are the lines `typemap: unable to find mapping...`, `GraphicsDeviceManager.ResetClientBounds`, and `Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #17`.

That said, those could be completely unrelated as similar messages appear when it loads correctly.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this but I've found a lot of issues with the handling of the backbuffer/clientWindow on Android involving ResetClientBounds().

You can try my modified build if you want and see if that fixed it.
You can use the [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MonoGame.Framework.Android.9000/) or the [installer](https://github.com/nkast/XNAGameStudio/blob/master/MG%20SDK/MonoGameSetup.exe?raw=true).

It's required to to change ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.FullSensor 
in the Activity1.cs, otherwise it will fail to load.

Comment: Hm... So I've just tried using that library from NuGet and I still have the same problem. Still getting the `GraphicsDeviceManager.ResetClientBounds` diagnostic and `typemap: unable to find mapping to a managed type from Java type 'com/google/android/gles_jni/EGLSurfaceImpl'`. I'm not sure if those are even indicative of  the problem, they're just the only thing I've got that looks remotely significant.

Comment: How about the 'onWindowFocusChanged', did you override that method in Acitivity1.cs?